# c# - wpf - refresh picture between window switching

Tags: c#, wpf, image, picturebox

I have simple wpf app which consist of 2 windows: MainMenu and PictureWindow.
In MainMenu I have one button with click event which opens Picture Window:

```
private void btnOpenPicWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picWindow = new PictureWindow();
    Application.Current.MainWindow = picWindow;
    Close();
    picWindow.Show();
}
```

In PictureWindow I have `WindowsFormsHost` with `PictureBox`. In PictureWindow I receive image which I send from another app and I show it on `PictureBox`. PictureWindow also has a button with click event which goes back to MainMenu like this:

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mMenu = new MainWindow();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow = mMenu;
    Close();
    mMenu.Show();
}
```

Everything is ok when I open MainWindow and then PictureWindow. The problem is when I go back from PictureWindow to MainMenu and then once again to PictureWindow and if I send picture to my `PictureBox` it does not refresh. I receive the image cause I see it during debbuging but my `PictureBox` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to re-initialize your window with your picture every time you click on the button on your MainWindow.

You can change [`LoadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww2xzydc(v=vs.110).aspx) for [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6ak7was(v=vs.110).aspx) if you'd like to load your image with an Asynchronous or Synchronous method.

**WPF PictureWindow:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.PictureWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PictureWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
            <wf:PictureBox x:Name="pbImage" SizeMode="AutoSize"></wf:PictureBox>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# PictureWindow:**

```
public partial class PictureWindow : Window
{
    public string imgsrc = string.Empty;
    public PictureWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbImage.LoadAsync(imgsrc);
    }
}
```

**C# MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    PictureWindow window;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window = new PictureWindow();
    window.imgsrc = textBox1.Text.Trim(); //Here you update your "Source" for your image.
    window.Show();
}
```